# Android: waiting for a bitmap to load

Tags: android, bitmap, nullpointerexception, scaling

I'm trying to load a Bitmap from a resource and then scale it to the size I want. The thing is, when I try to change its size, it returns a NullPointerException. I imagine this is because BitmapFactory loads and decodes the image on another Thread, and my code goes on without it being finished. Then it gets to the resizing before this process is done.
At least that's what I thought. But then I tried to check in between if my "image" was null, and it wasn't... so I am not quite sure of what's going on.

```
 public void setImage(int id, float w){
    image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Help.helperActivity.getResources(), id);

    while(image == null){ // this never runs, so image can't be null
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    float ratio = image.getWidth() / image.getHeight();
    Log.d("tag", "ratio: " + ratio);
    float h = w / ratio;
    image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, (int) (w*Help.pw), (int) (h*Help.ph), true);
}
```

EDIT: Here's the stacktrace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
                                                                         Process: com.example.nicolas.vidalvsep, PID: 2585
                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Bitmap.setHasAlpha(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                             at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:883)
                                                                             at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:856)
                                                                             at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:787)
                                                                             at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:663)
                                                                             at com.example.nicolas.vidalvsep.Sprite.setImage(Sprite.java:92)
                                                                             at com.example.nicolas.vidalvsep.Vidal.<init>(Vidal.java:14)
                                                                             at com.example.nicolas.vidalvsep.GameView.initialize(GameView.java:72)
                                                                             at com.example.nicolas.vidalvsep.GameView.gameLoop(GameView.java:51)
                                                                             at com.example.nicolas.vidalvsep.GameView.access$000(GameView.java:16)
                                                                             at com.example.nicolas.vidalvsep.GameView$1.run(GameView.java:43)
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: `BitmapFactory` does not perform its work on a separate thread. You'll have to look in the stack trace to see what exactly is throwing the Exception. If you want some help reading it, you'll need to [edit] your question with the complete trace, and the parts of your code it references, if not already posted.

Comment: I've added the stack trace to the post

Comment: Hmm, looks like the native method to create a `Bitmap` is failing and returning null. Maybe it's running out of memory? What are the dimensions you end up passing to `createScaledBitmap()`? What happens if you try with smaller images and dimensions?